# Build.xml setup for continuous integration

Tags: deployment, ant, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup my `build.xml` to reference the ant-salesforce.jar from my project checkout. The directory structure is similar to this:

```
Project Dir
-> src
-> ant-salesforce.jar
-> build.xml
```

I am trying to reference the `ant-salesforce.jar` from the root directory of the project in my `build.xml` as shown below:

```
<project name="Test" default="test" basedir=".">

    <property environment="env"/>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="./ant-salesforce.jar" />
      </classpath>
  </taskdef>

    <target name="retrieve">
        <sf:retrieve username="${SRC_USERNAME}" password="${SRC_PASSWD}" serverurl="${SRC_URL}" retrieveTarget="src" unpackaged="src/package.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deployValidate">
        <sf:deploy username="${DEST_USERNAME}" password="${DEST_PASSWD}" serverurl="${DEST_URL}" deployRoot="src" rollbackOnError="true" checkonly="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <sf:deploy username="${DEST_USERNAME}" password="${DEST_PASSWD}"    serverurl="${DEST_URL}" deployRoot="src" rollbackOnError="true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

However, it keeps giving me the following error:

> ```
> build.xml:12: The prefix "sf" for element "sf:retrieve" is not bound.
> ```

Am I missing something when including the reference to the `ant-salesforce.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the namespace declaration for `sf` in the `<project>` node.

```
<project name="Test" xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce" basedir=".">
```

Comment: Hey Mark that worked!! But how do I know whether its using the ant-salesforce.jar from my project dir or one from the ant lib directory? UPDATE: removed the ant-salesforce.jar from ant lib directory and it still worked. Thanks